# Simple inequality with natural logarithm

Tags: logarithms

I need to calculate such inequality.

$ \ln\frac{2x}{x-1} \geq 0 $

I'm new to concept of $ \ln$ and clueless how to move on. Any tips?

Comment: Do you at least know for which $x$ the formula is well defined?

Comment: Hint: this is equivalent to $\frac{2x}{x-1}\ge1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**:

1. You have to specify the domain of validity of this inequation: $\dfrac{2x}{x-1}$ has to be defined and $>0$. This means
   $$\frac{x}{x-1}\;\text{ defined and }>0\iff x(x-1)>0. $$
2. In this domain of validity, the log is non-negative if and only if
   $$\frac{2x}{x-1}\ge 1. $$

Comment: Thanks. May I ask where the 2x/(x-1) >= 1 came from?

Comment: $\ln 1=0$, and the logarithm is an increasing function.

Comment: Ahahahh :-) "maniac".

Comment: @Sebastiano: I might have said ‘psychopath’…